# IIS 7 UrlReferrer throws exception

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

When I get referrer url, IIS 7 throws an exception. My code like this:

```
var referrer = Request.UrlReferrer == null ? null : Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri;
```

Application throws an ArgumentException with error message,

> "Value does not fall within the expected range."

There is no problem in IIS 6.

This exception occurs when the page is navigated with "Response.Redirect"

Application main page has an Response.Redirect method according to role of current user. User main page throws this exception.

How can get Referrer URL in IIS 7.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ran into similar problem when I tried to access the request object from a System.Threading.Task launched in the request processing. 
I'm using the task to reduce response time - in my case most of the processing can be performed after request is sent.
That is, I had something like:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    new System.Threading.Task(() => {

        // here I used this.Request.UrlReferrer and got weird ArgumenException error

    }).Start();

    return someActionResultThatDoesntRequireProcessing;
}
```

I've extracted UrlReferrer (and other this.Request.stuff that I needed) in delayed processing) into a separate "closure" variable (I've chosen them to have the very basic types):

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    var urlReferrerAbs = this.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri;
    var clientAddress = this.Request.UserHostAddress;
    // save other stuff from the request object

    new System.Threading.Task(() => {

        // here I used urlReferrerAbs instead of this.Request.UrlReferrer and the error has gone!

    }).Start();

    return someActionResultThatDoesntRequireProcessing;
}
```

That worked for me.

Comment: So, I must get referrer url before redirect the page.

Comment: Maybe, since some context for obtaining all Request properties correctly may have lost after redirecting as well as after switching to another thread.

Comment: @hanzala could you elaborate on what solved your problem? Was it the exact code LVR posted? Thanks!

Comment: I send UrlReferrer to async method as parameter. I didn't sen Request object as parameter.